# Is it possible to display the loading indicator until the task node response is completed?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm trying to display image until the task node response is not complete. I'm using below code. But, Still It's showing blank Screen.

```
m.LoaderScreen = m.top.findNode("LoaderScreen") 
m.LoaderScreen.visible = true 
m.APIResponse = CreateObject("roSGNode", "APIResponse") 
m.APIResponse.control = "RUN" 
m.LoaderScreen.visible = false
```

Anyone suggest any other way to do this?

**Edited Post**

Task node :

```
<field id = "response" type = "string" />

m.top.response = "My Response"
```

MainScene :

```
m.APIResponse.observeField("response", "onScreenResponse")

sub onScreenResponse()
m.LoaderScreen.visible = false
end sub
```

**Updated Post**

**First Way**

MainScene.xml

```
<Group id="LoaderScreen" visible="false">
    <LayoutGroup translation="[640,360]" horizAlignment="center" vertAlignment="center">
    <BusySpinner id="LoadingIndicator" clockwise="true" spinInterval="2"  uri="pkg:/images/loader.png"/>
    </LayoutGroup>
</Group>
```

MainScene.brs

```
sub Show(args as Object)
m.LoaderScreen = m.top.findNode("LoaderScreen")
m.LoaderScreen.visible = true
m.LoadingIndicator = m.top.findNode("LoadingIndicator")
m.LoadingIndicator.control = "start"

?"m.LoadingIndicator : "m.LoadingIndicator

?"First : m.LoadingIndicator.visible : "m.LoadingIndicator.visible 'true

m.FirstNode= CreateObject("roSGNode", "FirstNode")
m.FirstNode.control = "RUN"

?"Second : m.LoadingIndicator.visible : "m.LoadingIndicator.visible 'true

 m.SecondNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "SecondNode")
 m.SecondNode.control = "RUN"

?"Third : m.LoadingIndicator.visible : "m.LoadingIndicator.visible 'true

m.ThirdNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "ThirdNode")
m.ThirdNode.control = "RUN"

?"Fourth : m.LoadingIndicator.visible : "m.LoadingIndicator.visible 'true

m.FourthNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "FourthNode")
m.FourthNode.control = "RUN"

?"Five : m.LoadingIndicator.visible : "m.LoadingIndicator.visible 'true

m.LoadingIndicator.control = "stop"
m.LoaderScreen.visible = false
end sub
```

```
m.LoadingIndicator : <Component: roSGNode:BusySpinner> =
{
    clockwise: true
    control: invalid
    poster: <Component: roSGNode:Poster>
    spinInterval: 2
    uri: "pkg:/images/loader.png"
    childRenderOrder: "last"
    clippingRect: <Component: roAssociativeArray>
    enableRenderTracking: true
    inheritParentOpacity: true
    inheritParentTransform: true
    muteAudioGuide: false
    opacity: 1
    renderPass: 0
    renderTracking: "none"
    rotation: 0
    scale: <Component: roArray>
    scaleRotateCenter: <Component: roArray>
    translation: <Component: roArray>
    visible: true
    change: <Component: roAssociativeArray>
    focusable: false
    focusedChild: <Component: roInvalid>
    id: "LoadingIndicator"
}
```

Currently, I doing like this. Here, I found m.LoadingIndicator.visible value **true** After, Run a Every Single Task node. But, When I start the Application. It's Automatically blank screen above the m.LoadingIndicator.

**Second Way**

I'm trying to Display Loading Indicator in-between the splash Screen and landing page. I already tried What you suggested. like below. Does anything change need on this?

Using below way I tried with Task node state.
**Loading Indicator displays Using both the ways.**
But, Above the Loading indicator, It displays a one blank screen Automatically When the Task node is running. I also tried creating a new Channel. But, Here also Result is the same.

MainScene.xml

```
<Group id="LoaderScreen" visible="false">
<LayoutGroup translation="[640,360]" horizAlignment="center" vertAlignment="center">
<BusySpinner id="LoadingIndicator" clockwise="true" spinInterval="2"  uri="pkg:/images/loader.png"/>
</LayoutGroup>
```

MainScene.brs

```
sub Show(args as Object)
m.LoaderScreen = m.top.findNode("LoaderScreen")
m.LoadingIndicator = m.top.findNode("LoadingIndicator")

m.FirstNode= CreateObject("roSGNode", "FirstNode")
m.FirstNode.observeField("state", "onTaskStateChanged")
m.FirstNode.control = "RUN"

m.SecondNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "SecondNode")
m.SecondNode.observeField("state", "onTaskStateChanged")
m.SecondNode.control = "RUN"

m.ThirdNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "ThirdNode")
m.ThirdNode.observeField("state", "onTaskStateChanged")
m.ThirdNode.control = "RUN"

m.FourthNode = CreateObject("roSGNode", "FourthNode")
m.FourthNode.observeField("state", "onTaskStateChanged")
m.FourthNode.control = "RUN"

end sub
sub onTaskStateChanged()
?"MainScene :: onTaskStateChanged()"
    if m.FirstNode <> invalid then
        if m.FirstNode.state = "run"
            m.LoaderScreen.visible = true
            m.LoadingIndicator.control = "start"
        end if
    end if
    if m.SecondNode <> invalid then
        if m.SecondNode.state = "run"
            m.LoaderScreen.visible = true
            m.LoadingIndicator.control = "start"
        end if
    end if
    if m.ThirdNode <> invalid then
        if m.ThirdNode.state = "run"
            m.LoaderScreen.visible = true
            m.LoadingIndicator.control = "start"
        end if
    end if
    if m.FourthNode <> invalid then
        if m.FourthNode.state = "run"
            m.LoaderScreen.visible = true
            m.LoadingIndicator.control = "start"
        else if m.FourthNode.state = "stop"
            m.LoaderScreen.visible = false
            m.LoadingIndicator.control = "stop"
        end if
    end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for the task node response object.
In this observer call m.loaderscreen.visible = false.
It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you For your Reply. You want to say it this way. I edit my Post. Here I used 5 Task nodes So, I need to Put Loading Screen First to Firth. So, I will apply the Same Logic between all Five Task node. Right?

Comment: Its not mandatory to add observer to task node. @NikunjChaklasiya, It totally depends on your implementation how you are handling the response. Where ever you are handling the response, set the visibility of the loading indicator as false there. As you are asking for 5 task node, it depends on your requirements and implementation. If your task execution starting from one task and without user interference going on to 5th task you can make it visible on first task and hide it on 5th task.

Comment: I updated My Post. Please Check. Here, I mentioned Two Ways. Loading Indicator displays Using both the ways. But, Above the Loading indicator, It displays a one blank screen Automatically When the Task node is running.

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Any suggestion. I tried this issue with both BrightScript Component(SGDex Component and normal BrightScript Component). I applied both ways in both components As I mentioned above. In normal BrightScript Component display an automatically Splash Screen until a TaskNode Response is not complete. But In SGDex Component display and automatically Blank Screen Until a TaskNode Response is not Complete.